# 2つの配列を紐づけて，一方の配列の昇順又は降順にソート関連して他方の配列を並び替えたい

Tags: ruby

2つの配列`arr`と`brr`があったとき，`arr`の昇順又は降順のソートに関連して`brr`を並び替えたいです．
2次元配列でもHashでも構いません（手法が他にあれば教えていただきたいです）
ご教授よろしくおねがいします．

具体例を以下に示します．`arr`と`brr`の配列の長さは同一の条件です．

```
arr = [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
brr = [17, 15, 13, 10, 19, 12, 14, 18]

# 例えば以下
arr.sort!
# => [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# => brrは[13, 10, 19, 17, 18, 12, 15, 14]と並び替えられる
```

Comment: 配列のインデックスで関連付いているということでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick そうです．`arr`のインデックスと`brr`のインデックスが関連づいているということになります．

Comment: `values_at` を使う方法もあります。`brr.values_at(*arr.map.with_index.sort.map(&:last).index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arr と brr のペアの配列を作ってからソートするというのはどうでしょうか。

```
arr = [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
brr = [17, 15, 13, 10, 19, 12, 14, 18]

hoge = arr.zip(brr)
#=> [[5, 17], [8, 15], [1, 13], [3, 10], [4, 19], [7, 12], [9, 14], [6, 18]]
fuga = hoge.sort_by(&:first)
#=> [[1, 13], [3, 10], [4, 19], [5, 17], [6, 18], [7, 12], [8, 15], [9, 14]]
arr = fuga.map(&:first)
#=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
brr = fuga.map(&:last)
#=> [13, 10, 19, 17, 18, 12, 15, 14]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby配列での解答は皆さんすでに書かれています。
NArrayでやるとこうなります。

```rb
require 'numo/narray'

a = Numo::Int8[5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
b = Numo::Int8[17, 15, 13, 10, 19, 12, 14, 18]

b[a.sort_index]
```

=> Numo::Int8(view)#shape=[8]
[13, 10, 19, 17, 18, 12, 15, 14]

Int8が対応できる範囲は狭いので、必要に応じてInt64やDFloatなどをお使いください。

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
brr = [17, 15, 13, 10, 19, 12, 14, 18]

zipped = arr.zip(brr)
zipped.sort!

sorted_brr = zipped.map { |pair| pair[1] }

p sorted_brr
# => [13, 10, 19, 17, 18, 12, 15, 14]
```

zip して sort して取り出すと良いと思います。

Comment: zip を使うと stable sort にならない場合があります。例えば、`arr = [5, 8, 1, 1, 4, 7, 9, 6]` の場合、結果が `[10, 13, 19, 17, 18, 12, 15, 14]` となります(13 と 10 の位置が逆転)。

Answer (score 0):

`sort!`メソッドを読んだときにローカル変数`brr`を書き換えたいのであれば `define_singleton_method` で`sort!`メソッドを定義しなおして、メソッド定義のブロックの中からローカル変数の中身を書き換えるとよさそうです

```rb
arr = [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
brr = [17, 15, 13, 10, 19, 12, 14, 18]

arr.define_singleton_method(:sort!) do
  map!.with_index { |*x| x }
  super()
  brr = map { |_, index| brr[index] }
  map!(&:first)
end

# 例えば以下
arr.sort!

p arr == [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
p brr == [13, 10, 19, 17, 18, 12, 15, 14]
```