# 配列arrayに対して変数inputの値に最も近いk個のarrayの要素のインデックスを取得したい

Tags: ruby

配列arrayに対して変数inputの値に最も近いk個のarrayの要素を取得できるメソッドが作りたいですが，方法がわかりません．
質問タイトルだけではよくわからないと思うので，以下の例を提示します．

配列`array`を以下と仮に定義する

```
array = [1.3, 1.4, 6.3, 2.9, 3.0]
```

ここで，`input`を以下と仮に定義する

```
input = 3.5
```

このとき，`k = 3`とすると`array`の要素で`input`に最も近い値3つは，

```
1.4, 2.9, 3.0
```

なので，返り値として，`[1, 3, 4]`をとる．
このようなメソッドを作りたいですが，わかりません．
どなたかご教授よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: [2つの配列を紐づけて，一方の配列の昇順又は降順にソート関連して他方の配列を並び替えたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57441/) と同様に、`array.map{|x| (x-input).abs}.with_index.sort.map(&:last)[0...k].sort` など。

Comment: @metropolis すみません，ありがとうございます．上記の`with_index`は`each_eith_index`でしょうか？

Comment: いえ、`with_index` です。なお、こちらの ruby の version は 2.5.5 です。

Comment: @metropolis 私のRubyのversionは`ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin16]`ですが，このversionでは`each_with_index`で大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: すみません、勘違いしていました。`each_with_index` で問題ありません。`array.map{|x| (x-input).abs}.each_with_index.sort.map(&:last)[0...k].sort`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

要素の値を取るならこれで

```
    array = [1.3, 1.4, 6.3, 2.9, 3.0]
    input = 3.5
    k = 3
    p array.min_by(k) { |x, _| (input - x).abs }
    # [3.0, 2.9, 1.4]
```

インデックスであれば

```
    array = [1.3, 1.4, 6.3, 2.9, 3.0]
    input = 3.5
    k = 3
    p array.each_with_index.min_by(k) { |x, _| (input - x).abs }.map(&:last)
    # [4, 3, 1]
```

でどうでしょう

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．下の回答の末尾に`.sort`をつければ質問と同様になるかと思うので，参考にさせていただきます．

Answer (score 0):

NArrayでは、ぱっと思いつくのは

```rb
require 'numo/narray'

na = Numo::SFloat[1.3, 1.4, 6.3, 2.9, 3.0]
idx = (na - 3.5).abs.sort_index
# [4, 3, 1, 0, 2]

na[idx]
# [3, 2.9, 1.4, 1.3, 6.3]

na[idx[0..2]]
# [3, 2.9, 1.4]
```

ですね。`abs` は絶対値です。オリジナルの配列における順番にこだわりがあるなら、

```rb
idx[0..2].sort
# [1, 3, 4]
```

です。